# Output Buffer shows "1"

Tags: php, function, ob-start

I have two functions:

```
core_function($atts) {
        (attributes)
        (core functions, a few loops, echoes, a lot of direct input)
    }
```

And that's how I display my function using output buffering (yes, I have to use it!).

```
display_function($atts) {
            (attributes)

                $output = ob_start();
                $output .= core_function($atts);
                $output .= ob_get_clean();

            return $output;
}
```

Everything is perfectly fine, but return $output shows not only core functions but also "1" before them. I have no idea where this "1" comes from. When I deletete ob_start(); and ob_get_clean(); it disappears. So I believe the output buffer is somehow adding this digit. But how, and why? It's a raw "1", not in a paragraph etc.

Normaly display_function($atts) shows, for example:

```
<div>This is Core Function!</div>
```

And with output buffering it displays:

```
1             <div>This is Core Function!</div>
```

Why is it happening? If it has something to do with my functions I'm saying again - the 1 is being displayed exactly BEFORE all the contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not how output buffering works.  `ob_start` returns TRUE or FALSE upon completion so you are concatenating a bunch of things that shouldn't be concatenated.  (The same goes for your call to core_function).

```
display_function($atts) {
     (attributes)

     ob_start();
     core_function($atts);
     return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Should work.  It turns on output buffering which will save all of your output (echo's and prints etc).  The call to ob_get_clean will return the contents of your buffered output.

Comment: amazing and fast answer, all I needed, thank you, thank you, thank you! Because just accepting your answer is not enough.